# p2 cannot be resolved to a variable due to if statements?

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

At the moment, i am making a noughts and crosses game with 2 different type of computer players. I want the user to input how many games to play and is he wants to play random or simple player. So i implemented a while loop and if statement respectively. However, due to the if statement my p2 can no longer be resolved to a variable and i don't know a way around this. Any help would be appreciated. This is only the main part of my code that has the error.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int Wins = 0;
    int Loses = 0;
    int Draws = 0;

    System.out.println("To choose player type Random or Simple");
    String ChoosePlayer = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Please enter the number of rounds you want to play:");
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    int Rounds = 0;


while(Rounds < i){
    NCGridV3 theGrid = new NCGridV3(gridSize, gridSize);
    GameRunnerV3 theGame = new GameRunnerV3();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);        // only needed if we include human players 

    HumanPlayer p1 = new HumanPlayer(sc, theGame);

    if(ChoosePlayer == "Simple"){
        SimpleComputerPlayer p2 = new SimpleComputerPlayer();
        p2.setMySymbol(SquareStatus.NOUGHT);
        }

    else if(ChoosePlayer == "Random"){
        RandomComputerPlayer p2 = new RandomComputerPlayer();
        p2.setMySymbol(SquareStatus.NOUGHT);
        }


    p1.setMySymbol(SquareStatus.CROSS);

    System.out.println(INITIAL_INSTRUCTIONS);


    NCPlayer nextToPlay = p1;       // arbitrary decision that p1 goes first

    while (theGrid.getGameStatus() == GameStatus.STILLPLAYING)
    {
        GridCoordinate nextMove = nextToPlay.getNextMove(theGrid) ;
        try
        {
            theGrid.setSquareStatus(nextMove.getRow(), nextMove.getCol(), nextToPlay.getMySymbol());
        } 
        catch (outOfRangeError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        // take turns 
        if(nextToPlay == p1)
            nextToPlay = p2;  // possible problem here
        else
            nextToPlay = p1;
```

Comment: Use a proper IDE, format your code properly and ensure that, you're not missing any semicolumns and braces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(ChoosePlayer == "Random"){
    RandomComputerPlayer p2 = new RandomComputerPlayer();
    p2.setMySymbol(SquareStatus.NOUGHT);
}
```

The issue is that you define `p2` inside the `if` block of instructions.

Variables are available after they have been defined, inside of the block in which thehy have been defined. Once the compiler compiles code outside that block of instructions, `p2` is no longer defined.

So, just define `p2` in the block that shares it (usually a method body or as attribute of a class) and use it there. Of course, the type of variable must be such that it allows assignation of any of the possible value (in this example, it must be a superclass/interface that both `SimpleComputerPlayer`and `RandomComputerPlayer` extend/implement from.

```
ComputerPlayer p2 = null;  <---
if (ChoosePlayer.equals("Simple")) {
   p2 = new SimpleComputerPlayer();
} else if (ChoosePlayer.equals("Random")){{
   p2 = new RandomComputerPlayer();
}
```

Note that you should always assign a value to p2; otherwise if you try to use it in an expression the compiler will cause an error because it does not allow to use uninitialized values in expressions, and it is not clear for it that the value will have been initialized (what if `ChoosePlayer` is neither `Simple` nor `Random`)

Additionally, check the proper way to name variables in Java and how to perform String (and other object) comparations...

Answer (score 0):

Create a common Interface / Superclass for  RandomComputerPlayer and SimpleComputerPlayer and just define the variable outside of the if/else block:

```
ComputerPlayer p2;
if(......) {
    p2 = new SimpleComputerPlayer();
} else {
    p2 = new RandomComputerPlayer();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using two different classes to represent the 'p2' player. I suggest the following:
First, create an `abstract class ComputerPlayer`

Then, change `SimpleComputerPlayer` and `RandomComputerPlayer` to extend `ComputerPlayer`.

Then, in your if statements :

use `ComputerPlayer p2 = new SimpleComputerPlayer();`

or `ComputerPlayer p2 = new SimpleComputerPlayer();`

Put common code in each of these player classes into `ComputerPlayer`